# Stream Webcam via command line to vlc

Tags: sound, webcam, vlc, streaming, avconv

I've spent the morning doing searches and can't find any tutorials on how to stream my webcam(with sound) so I can watch it remotely on VLC. I have avconv installed, and can stream to twitch just fine, but can't for the life of me find how to stream so I can stream directly to vlc.

I've found a cvlc command that I can stream just fine, but it doesn't any sound.

Comment: There is an external link guide you might find usefull  --- http://xmodulo.com/2013/09/live-stream-video-webcam-linux.html

Comment: I've used that very link @Tasos and I can stream video, but not sound.

Comment: I had both `hw:0.0` and `hw:1.1` here as sound capture devices, did you try all options in your setup?

Comment: yeah I @SylvainPineau I've tried hw:0.0 hw:1.1 hw:0,0 and hw:0,1 and no joy, which is why I'm asking for an avconc solution.